# Templated Game Resource Manager

Tags: c++, memory-management, pointers

After scanning some of the questions here about resource managers I've made some changes, and while it is much improved I still feel it's not quite up to snuff.

It tried to make it work for all data types that inherit from resource and load the resource automatically if not yet available.

**Resource.h**

```
class Resource {
public:
    Resource() {};
    virtual ~Resource() {};


    virtual void load(const std::string& path) = 0;
    virtual void unload() = 0;

protected:
    unsigned mResourceId;
    std::string mResourcePath;

};

// Custom destructor for smart pointer
struct ResourceFree {
    void operator()(Resource* resource) {
        resource->unload();
        delete resource;
    }
};

class Texture : public Resource {
public:
    int width;
    int height;
    int channels;
    unsigned char* data;

    void load(const std::string& path);
    void unload();
};
```

And **ResourceManager.h**

```
class ResourceManager {
public:
    template <typename T>
    T& load(const std::string& name) {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Resource, T>::value, "T must inherit from Resource");

        auto found = resources.find(name);
        if (found == resources.end()) {
            T* resource_instance = new T;
            Resource* resource_base = dynamic_cast<Resource*>(resource_instance);
            resource_base->load(name);
            resources.emplace(name, resource_base);

            return *resource_instance;
        } else {
            return *dynamic_cast<T*>(found->second.get());
        }
    }

    void unload(const std::string& path) {
        resources.erase(path);
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Resource, ResourceFree>> resources;
};
```

I'm doing a lot of dynamic casting, but I don't see how to do it differently. Maybe there are some C++17 things that make this a little nicer? Or perhaps I'm going at it the wrong way

Comment: I believe `std::any` will do as nicely as inheritance here. You're doing casts anyway, and `std::any` will provide you a little more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Small nitpicks

- AFAICT `Resource::mResourceId` is unused, and `Resource::mResourcePath` might not be necessary (in worst case, it could be queried from the `ResourceManager`).
- For better portability, make the type of `Texture::data` `uint8_t`, as `char` might not be 8 bits wide on all platforms.
- Inconsistent naming: sometimes it's `name`, sometimes it's `path`. Choose one and stick with it!
- Also, hopefully all paths follow the same convention (e.g. no backslashes under windows, no superfluous slashes, etc.), otherwise a resource with the same physical location might be loaded for multiple different paths. Maybe introduce a way to make paths compliant to a convention (e.g. a method `make_unique_path` or similar).

## Implementation

- If a resource `path` is already loaded as another resource type, `ResourceManager::load` returns a dangling (null) reference. Maybe throw an exception instead?

## Design

- Are there any actual cases where `Resource::unload()` actually has to do anything (e.g. write the resource back)? Usually resources are read-only, so this member function might not be needed.
- I would make it the `Resource` constructors responsibility to load the resource (and the destructors responsibility to unload it if necessary). This way, there is never an "unloaded/not yet loaded" state of a resource that has to be checked everywhere.
- `ResourceManager` has a communication issue if the same resource is required by 2 or more clients: Who does the cleanup (who gets to call `ResourceManager::unload(const std::string&)`)? If done to early, every other client has a dangling reference. If not done at all, the resource will only be cleaned up when the `ResourceManager` is destructed - which uses memory unnecessarily in the meantime. (Careful: calling virtual functions from constructor/destructor is [a bad idea](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/OOP50-CPP.+Do+not+invoke+virtual+functions+from+constructors+or+destructors)!)
- Why store a `std::unique_ptr` in `ResourceManager::resources` if the resource is going to be shared anyways? This is **the** usage `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` were made for!

Example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

class Resource {
public:
    Resource(const std::string&) {}
    virtual ~Resource() {}
};

class Texture : public Resource {
public:
    int width;
    int height;
    int channels;
    uint8_t* data;

    Texture(const std::string& path) : Resource(path) {
        load(path);
    }

    virtual ~Texture() {
        // if needed for whatever reason
        unload();
    }
protected:
    void load(const std::string& path) {
        // loading logic in here
    }
    
    void unload() {
        // unloading logic in here
    }
};

class ResourceManager {
public:
    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> load(const std::string& path) {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Resource, T>::value, "T must inherit from Resource");
        
        auto res = resources[path].lock();
        if(!res) {
            // assuming constructor loads resource
            resources[path] = res = std::make_shared<T>(path);
        }

        auto return_value = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(res);
        if(!return_value) {
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Resource '") + path + "' is already loaded as another type");
        }
        return return_value;
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::weak_ptr<Resource>> resources;
};
```

Some benefits of this design:

- Resource cleanup is handled by `std::shared_ptr`.
- Resources are unloaded as soon as they aren't needed anymore.
- No dangling references!
- Additional error handling if resource with the same `name` as another resource type is already loaded
- `ResourceFree` isn't needed anymore, because the usual destructor already does all the work.

## Other considerations

- `path` gets passed around a lot. While I get that the high-level caller would uses that one, it might be more fitting to pass a stream (or maybe file handle / pointer to a byte array / a `gsl::span`) to the resource constructor. This way, the resource doesn't have to care whether it's loaded from disk, or from a zip file, or from a network stream, or from (somewhere else). However, this would actually require an ID to uniquely identify a resource (how would a path refer to a resource transmitted over the net?) - which by itself isn't a bad idea if used correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried applying your example and it had some errors that I could fix myself, but I'm stuck on the "res = std::makle_shared<T>(path);" where it gives me the following error:     cannot convert from 'std::shared_ptr<Texture>' to 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>'. Which needs to be a shared_ptr<Resource>, just like res. How do I do this?

Comment: @Eejin: whoops, my bad, forgot to derive `Texture` from `Resource`. That should fix it.

Comment: I had already done that, but it wasn't the issue. I think its having trouble with this line: "resources[path] = res = std::make_shared<T>(path);". If I remove it the compiler doesn't report the error, (but it doesn't work anymore obviously).

Comment: @Eejin: weird, I have no trouble compiling the code as-is. Which compiler are you using? [ideone](https://ideone.com/n09q6x)

Comment: Visual Studio 15.3.5 2017 with /std:c++ latest flag enabled.Edit: Oops, I see I forgot to set the inheritance public " Texture : public Resource". It compiles now albeit with some warnings.

Comment: @Eejin: I have no trouble compiling here (or in multiple online compilers, with a 2-line main function added to force template instantiation, see ideone link in my last comment). Are you sure you are using the current version from the answer?

Comment: I had edited my previous comment, but I think that must've been just as you were typing your responce. It works now after setting it to public inheritance. Many thanks for your code review :)